# angular js href add unsafe in beginning of url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When trying to access

```
app://csttree?featuretype=cst_issue&verticalid=2132321&l1=3213&l2=3242
```

in my app, it's parsing the url to ==>

```
unsafe:app://csttree?featuretype=cst_issue&verticalid=2132321&l1=3213&l2=3242
```

Is there a way to avoid `unsafe` at the beginning of the url?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're calling `app://...`, but if you whitelist `app` that should do the trick:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|app):/);
    }
]);
```

Comment: Working fine.   Thanks William .

Comment: @PawanKumarSingh please upvote and mark as the accepted answer since that worked for you :)